# How to set a default editable string for raw_input?

Tags: python, input, raw-input

I'm using Python 2.7's `raw_input` to read from stdin.

I want to let the user change a given default string.

Code:

```
i = raw_input("Please enter name:")
```

Console:

```
Please enter name: Jack
```

The user should be presented with `Jack` but can change (backspace) it to something else.

The `Please enter name:` argument would be the prompt for `raw_input` and that part shouldn't be changeable by the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show default value for editing on Python input possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible)

Answer (score 83):

You could do:

```
i = raw_input("Please enter name[Jack]:") or "Jack"
```

This way, if user just presses return without entering anything, "i" will be assigned "Jack".

Comment: This doesn't fit the question. `Jack` is not editable.

Comment: But this is a common Unix pattern for providing default input.  If you want to accept the default just hit enter.

Comment: @chubbsondubs The question wasn't about _common Unix pattern_.

Answer (score 32):

**Python2.7 get raw_input and set a default value:**

Put this in a file called a.py:

```
import readline
def rlinput(prompt, prefill=''):
   readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
   try:
      return raw_input(prompt)
   finally:
      readline.set_startup_hook()

default_value = "an insecticide"
stuff = rlinput("Caffeine is: ", default_value)
print("final answer: " + stuff)
```

Run the program, it stops and presents the user with this:

```
el@defiant ~ $ python2.7 a.py
Caffeine is: an insecticide
```

The cursor is at the end, user presses backspace until 'an insecticide' is gone, types something else, then presses enter:

```
el@defiant ~ $ python2.7 a.py
Caffeine is: water soluable
```

Program finishes like this, final answer gets what the user typed:

```
el@defiant ~ $ python2.7 a.py 
Caffeine is: water soluable
final answer: water soluable
```

**Equivalent to above, but works in Python3:**

```
import readline    
def rlinput(prompt, prefill=''):
   readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
   try:
      return input(prompt)
   finally:
      readline.set_startup_hook()

default_value = "an insecticide"
stuff = rlinput("Caffeine is: ", default_value)
print("final answer: " + stuff)
```

**More info on what's going on here:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533142/445131

Comment: Is this supposed to work in Windows too or does it only work in Linux?

Comment: you are genius! TY so much!

Comment: @ChaimG: Unfotunately: `pip install readline` yields `error: this module is not meant to work on Windows`

Answer (score 7):

In dheerosaur's answer If user press Enter to select default value in reality it wont be saved as python considers it as '' string so Extending a bit on what dheerosaur.

```
default = "Jack"
user_input = raw_input("Please enter name: %s"%default + chr(8)*4)
if not user_input:
    user_input = default
```

Fyi .. The `ASCII value` of backspace is `08`

Comment: That's a neat trick, thanks. Still not what I want because the user can't really change the given default string or use the arrow keys for navigation. Of course one could work around that but that's a bit out of scope for such a little feature.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'chr(8)*len(default)' ?

Comment: `Jack` is just printed but not set as default.

Answer (score 6):

I only add this because you should write a simple function for reuse.  Here is the one I wrote:

```
def default_input( message, defaultVal ):
    if defaultVal:
        return raw_input( "%s [%s]:" % (message,defaultVal) ) or defaultVal
    else:
        return raw_input( "%s " % (message) )
```

Comment: This doesn't fit the question.

Comment: I re-read the question and I still think it does.  You might want to explain your position better.

Comment: @chubbsndubs Cited from the question: "but can change (backspace) it to something else". This means that the user should be able to edit the default value.

Comment: You're being overly pedantic.  My suggestion gives the OP the feature they requested in a slightly different way.  It's implied that if the OP can alter their requirements, which I see as very minor change, then this solution will work for them.  If not fine the answer is you can't do it with raw_input(), and you're looking at a non-portable solution using readline maybe.

Answer (score 5):

On platforms with `readline`, you can use the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533142/1090657

On Windows, you can use the msvcrt module:

```
from msvcrt import getch, putch

def putstr(str):
    for c in str:
        putch(c)

def input(prompt, default=None):
    putstr(prompt)
    if default is None:
        data = []
    else:
        data = list(default)
        putstr(data)
    while True:
        c = getch()
        if c in '\r\n':
            break
        elif c == '\003': # Ctrl-C
            putstr('\r\n')
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        elif c == '\b': # Backspace
            if data:
                putstr('\b \b') # Backspace and wipe the character cell
                data.pop()
        elif c in '\0\xe0': # Special keys
            getch()
        else:
            putch(c)
            data.append(c)
    putstr('\r\n')
    return ''.join(data)
```

Note that arrows keys don't work for the windows version, when it's used, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

For **windows** users with `gitbash/msys2` or `cygwin` you can use it's built in readline through python subprocess. It is a sort of hack but works quite well and doesn't require any third party code. For personal tools this works really well.

Msys2 specific: If you want ctrl+c to **immediately** exit, you will need to run your program with
`winpty python program.py`

```
import subprocess
import shlex

def inputMsysOrCygwin(prompt = "", prefilled = ""):
    """Run your program with winpty python program.py if you want ctrl+c to behave properly while in subprocess"""
    try:
        bashCmd = "read -e -p {} -i {} bash_input; printf '%s' \"$bash_input\"".format(shlex.quote(prompt), shlex.quote(prefilled))
        userInput = subprocess.check_output(["sh", "-c", bashCmd], encoding='utf-8')
        return userInput
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Invalid environment: inputMsysOrCygwin can only be run from bash where 'read' is available.")

userInput = ""
try:
    #cygwin or msys2 shell
    userInput = inputMsysOrCygwin("Prompt: ", "This is default text")
except FileNotFoundError:
    #cmd or powershell context where bash and read are not available 
    userInput = input("Prompt [This is default text]: ") or "This is default text"

print("userInput={}".format(userInput))
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this: `raw_input("Please enter name: Jack" + chr(8)*4)`

The ASCII value of `backspace` is `08`.

Comment: `Jack` is just printed but not set as default.

Comment: @buhtz Thanks for pointing out. Please feel free to edit the answer.