# How to define default value if empty user input in Python?

Tags: python, user-input, default-value

Here I have to set the default value if the user will enter the value from the keyboard. Here is the code that user can enter value:

```
input = int(raw_input("Enter the inputs : "))
```

Here the value will be assigned to a variable `input` after entering the value and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there any method that if we don't enter the value and directly hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the variable will be directly assigned to a default value, say as `input = 0.025`?

Comment: ... and that will fail if the user just hits Enter

Comment: `input` is a built-in function in Python, you might wanna use a different variable name...

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [How to set a default string for raw_input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403138/how-to-set-a-default-string-for-raw-input)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Python 3:

```
inp = int(input('Enter the inputs: ').strip() or "42")
```

Python 2:

```
inp = int(raw_input('Enter the inputs: ').strip() or "42")
```

How does it work?

If nothing was entered then `input`/`raw_input` returns empty string. Empty string in Python is `False`, `bool("") -> False`. Operator `or` returns first truthy value, which in this case is `"42"`.

This is not sophisticated input validation. It's slightly more robust with the addition of `.strip()`.  That handles the possibility of the user entering spaces or other whitespace, which then would be `True`.

Comment: Isn't it bad practise to name the variable as 'input'?

Comment: It depends on the context, if the message would say "enter how many apples you have", then yes `input` would be very bad name.

Comment: @AnchithAcharya, I would agree it's bad practice as `input` is a built-in function and you would be replacing that function with the output of the statement.

In practice it may not be a big deal, but if you needed to ask for `input` again later in the function you would find it not working as expected as `input` would now be an `int`.

Answer (score 17):

One way is:

```
default = 0.025
input = raw_input("Enter the inputs : ")
if not input:
   input = default
```

Another way can be:

```
input = raw_input("Number: ") or 0.025
```

Same applies for Python 3, but using `input()`:

```
ip = input("Ip Address: ") or "127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> try:
        input= int(raw_input("Enter the inputs : "))
    except ValueError:
        input = 0

Enter the inputs : 
>>> input
0
>>>
```

Comment: There are [many reasons not to use exceptions for control flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control).

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [`click` library](https://click.palletsprojects.com) for that, which provides lots of useful functionality for command-line interfaces:

```
import click

number = click.prompt("Enter the number", type=float, default=0.025)
print(number)
```

Examples of input:

```
Enter the number [0.025]: 
 3  # Entered some number
3.0
```

or

```
Enter the number [0.025]: 
    # Pressed enter wihout any input
0.025
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first input a string, then check for zero length and valid number:

```
input_str = raw_input("Ender the number:")

if len(input_str) == 0:
    input_number = DEFAULT
else:
    try:
        input_number = int(input_str)
    except ValueError:
        # handle input error or assign default for invalid input
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the above answers are correct but for Python 3.7, here is what you can do to set the default value.

```
user_input = input("is this ok ? - [default:yes] \n")
if len(user_input) == 0 :
    user_input = "yes"
```

Comment: This is the same idea as in [Ber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22402660/7851470). Also, you might wanna change "Python 3.7" to just "Python 3" because [`input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) was there before that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to validate user input to be a number and also set default value if he enters nothing.

```
while True:
    luckyNo = input("Enter your lucky number - [default:108]: ").strip()
    if luckyNo.isdigit(): # check if user entered a number
        luckyNo = int(luckyNo) # convert entered number to integer
        break
    else:  
        if not luckyNo: # user entered nothing
            print("You entered nothing. Using default value...")
            luckyNo = 108 # set default value
            break
        else: # user entered something other than a number
            print("Wrong input!. Try again.")

print("Your lucky number is " + str(luckyNo))
```