# How to get a null input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the user to input values only to the needed variables (Eg: If you need to get the power ignore the input power and only input to the remaining variables). I would really appreciate the help.

Code:

```
Power = int(input("Power: "))
Current = int(input("Cuurent: "))
Voltage = int(input("Voltage: "))
def P(C,V):
    return C * V
def C(P,V):
    return P / V
def V(P,C):
    return P / C
if Power == None:
    print(P(Current,Voltage))
elif Current == None:
    print(C(Power,Voltage))
else:
    print(V(Power,Current))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tharu\Desktop\Python.py", line 1, in <module>
    Power = int(input("Power: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Did you try using an `if` statement to check if the string is empty before trying to convert it to an integer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default values on empty user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402548/default-values-on-empty-user-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert it to an `int` immediately and check to see the truthiness of the input

```py
Power = input("Power: ")
Current = input("Cuurent: ")
Voltage = input("Voltage: ")
def P(C,V):
    return C * V
def C(P,V):
    return P / V
def V(P,C):
    return P / C
if not Power:
    print(P(int(Current),int(Voltage)))
elif not Current:
    print(C(int(Power),int(Voltage)))
else:
    print(V(int(Power),int(Current)))

>>> Power:
>>> Cuurent: 2
>>> Voltage: 20
40
```

An empty string will report `False` so you can use that fact to know which input was left blank. Once you know that, then you can convert the others to an `int` within that portion of the code.

Comment: Don't use `bool` in boolean context, it's useless. Just do `if mystring:` to test if it's not empty, or `if not mystring:` to test if it's empty.

Answer (score -3):

You are getting this error because you are leaving the input blank. You need to put an integer value as input else you can condition the input function or use command line arguments.

Comment: The OP **wants** to be able to input an empty string to mean that he wants the value to be calculated from the other ones.