# How to have a default response in python input

Tags: python, input, default-value

I want to have a default response using python input function
i would like it to behave like so

```
response = input("Enter your response :", default="default response")
```

that would prompt the user : Enter your response : default response
where "default response" behave like if the user writted it so he can modify a text already written.

did'nt found anything about that in the docs but i guess it's possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define default value if empty user input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402548/how-to-define-default-value-if-empty-user-input-in-python)

Comment: A Python module which provides a  GUI interface such as PySimpleGUI makes it fairly easy to have a default input which the user can accept, edit or replace,

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's no way to give the user a pre-typed default value. But what you can do is prompt the user for input with the default value specified. If the user continues without entering anything then the code will consider the default value. **THOUGH IT IS NOT A GOOD PRACTICE**

For example,

```
age = input("Enter age or just press Return to accept the default of 18: ") or "18"
```

Comment: "THOUGH IT IS NOT A GOOD PRACTICE" Can you explain why?

Comment: From the user experience perspective. Users might not understand entering that field blank to consider the default input. From the code perspective, it's not a bad practice though. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I understand, but I think that entering nothing for default value is a common experience in CLI.

Comment: For techie people yes, but for naive users no.

Edit: Removed GUI-based applications since the input function is not used

Comment: @HarshDobariya I agree. Can `input` be used in GUI-based applications?

Comment: Oops.... missed on that

Answer (score 1):

## Use `or` operator

If the user just press enter, an empty string will be returned. [The truthiness of an empty string is `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/6251742), so the right operand will be evaluated and returned.

```py
response = input('Enter your response ["default response"]:') or "default response"
```

For this behavior:

> Enter your response : default response where "default response" behave like if the user writted it so he can modify a text already written.

No, it's not possible as far as I know.

#### About `or` returned value

`or` doesn't return a bool but the first `True` value or the right operand if both are `False`:

```py
>>> 10 or 42
10
>>> '' or 42
42
>>> 0 or ''
''
>>> '' or 0
0
```