# Python: pre-specify response to raw_input

Tags: python

Is it possible to pre-specify the response to a series of raw_input questions within a program?

as in, if somewhere in my program I have:

```
response = raw_input("Enter something: ")
```

can i specify before the program begins that I would like to have "something" entered at the command line?

Comment: What do you mean? Your question is vague. Someone can draw multiple interpretations from your question. Please clarify

Comment: What is *"something"*?

Comment: You mean, you want your program to support command line options?  Maybe look at `optparse` or how to work with `sys.argv`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion is here. The OP wants it to seem as if someone sat down and typed the string `something` when you weren't looking, as soon as you get to the `raw_input` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you'd like your program to instantly show something like this:

> Enter something: something **_**

<sub>(Where _ is the shell's caret)</sub>

So that if you pressed enter, `raw_input` would return the string "something" - or you could press Backspace and edit the pre-filled input.

---

The simple answer is *no*, you cannot do this. The problem is that it is not Python handling the input at that point - it is your shell (bash, cmd, etc.) Only after you type something and press enter is that input "delivered" back to Python.

A library like `readline` will allow for something like what you want, but will only work on versions of Python linked against readline (usually Linux).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505163) for more.

---

An alternative that many programs use is to show a default value after the prompt, which is assumed if no input is given. This function should mimic this behavior:

```
def raw_input_default(prompt, default):
    result = raw_input('{0} [{1}] '.format(prompt, default))
    if result == '':
        result = default
    return result
```

Usage:

```
>>> print raw_input_default('Enter name:', 'Joe')
Enter name: [Joe] John
John
>>> print raw_input_default('Enter name:', 'Joe')
Enter name: [Joe]
Joe
```

Comment: If this is indeed what the author is asking, you can get something awfully similar. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20351345/2297365) answer. It shows some value that you type over, and it's trivially simple to adapt so that you can press enter and have the response take on the default.

Comment: @HuuNguyen I wouldn't say "awfully similar". For example this doesn't provide the edit capabilities that a truly pre-filled solution would.

Answer (score 0):

To implement default when you prompt the user, simply check if the response is empty - and set your default. This is typical displayed like this:

```
value = raw_input('Would you like to continue? [Y/n]: ')
```

The capital letter signifies the default value if no value is set, and the `n` is the optional value that the user can enter:

```
value = raw_input('Would you like to continue? [Y/n]: ')

# Set the default to 'Y'
if not len(value.strip()):
     result = 'Y'
else:
     result = value
```