# Pre-initialize raw_input with default value

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, input

I have a "form" where I have a few `raw_input`s to get the user response.

Now I want them to be pre-initialized with a default value. Is there any way to fill these `raw_input` fields? Or is there a good alternative to `raw_input` where that is possible?

To clarify, I have something looking like this:

```
val = raw_input("Input val:")
```

What I want as output is the following:

```
Input val: default value
```

and I want the user to be able to erase or edit the default value as if they had written it themselves. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean a form with raw_input? They are usually two different things. In general, you can use e.g. `user_input = raw_input() or default_value`, but it's not totally clear what you're asking for.

Comment: I edited the question to show what I mean

Comment: You can't do that sort of thing with `raw_input`, no. You can tell the user what the default will be (per Elizion's answer, although I would factor out the default value to reduce duplication), but they can't interact with the prompt text.

Comment: Found a way to do it, see my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default editable string for raw\_input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403138/how-to-set-a-default-editable-string-for-raw-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found an answer myself after some more Googling. It can be done with `raw_input` when using the `readline` module as follows:

```
import readline

def pre_input_hook():
    readline.insert_text('DefaultValue')
    readline.redisplay()

readline.set_pre_input_hook(pre_input_hook)

while True:
    line = raw_input('Prompt ("stop" to quit): ')
    if line == 'stop':
        break
    print 'ENTERED: "%s"' % line
```

Or, to wrap it all in an easier-to-handle function based on [jonrsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588767/python-2-7-pre-initialize-raw-input/28604256?noredirect=1#comment45516370_28604256):

```
import readline

DEFAULT_TEXT = ''

def default_hook():
    """Insert some default text into the raw_input."""
    readline.insert_text(default_hook.default_text)
    readline.redisplay()

readline.set_pre_input_hook(default_hook)

def raw_input_default(prompt, default=None):
    """Take raw_input with a default value."""
    default_hook.default_text = DEFAULT_TEXT if default is None else default
    return raw_input(prompt)
```

Comment: Note that this isn't portable - it won't work on Windows machines.

Comment: Also, it's bad form to create a name in `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`, suggesting that it is constant, then subsequently change it.

Comment: One alternative option would be using a function attribute - see e.g. https://gist.github.com/textbook/a046aef433bb9b9d43c4

Comment: That looks cool. I haven't been doing Python for too long, so I don't know most of the less common concepts of Python. Do you mind if I put your code into the answer?

Comment: Not at all, go for it!

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input` is not like a web form. The name should give it away: all the function does is accept raw input (in the form of a string), optionally printing a prompt first. If you want a default value, you'll need to set it yourself as in [Elizion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28588925/2069350).

---

Now, that said, you *can* hack the input prompt to *look* sort of like what you want. **I do not recommend this at all**, but for the sake of completeness, give the code below a try in an interactive console:

```
default_val = 'default'
i = raw_input('Input val: {}\rInput val: '.format(default_val)) or default_val
```

Here I'm abusing the `\r` character to move the cursor back to the start of the prompt. Then I re-write the actual prompt part, leaving the cursor on the `d` character, so that the user can type "over" it.

You'll notice though that `"default"` is still displayed there until you've typed over all of it (at which point it's probably gone for good, depending on your console's behavior). But it's only *displayed*; not actually part of the input. If the user enters `"foo"` (which will make the prompt look like this: `Input val: fooult`), `i` will get the value of `"foo"`. If the user just presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering text, `i` will be the empty string, which is why the `or default_val` is still necessary in the code. All this is to say that **this is almost certainly not what you want to do.** If you want a web form, make a web form. `raw_input` (and for that matter, console I/O) was not made for this.

Comment: Actually, I found a way to do that cleanly. Have a look at my answer. Thanks for your answer though, I like the hack ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `raw_input()`'s like this such that if the user doesn't enter anything *(just hits enter)* the value will be set to "my_default":

```
i = raw_input("Input Something[my_default]:") or "my_default"
```

**EDIT:**: Regarding your question update, as was pointed out in the comments you cannot have that sort of user interaction using `raw_input()`.

Comment: Hmm, that works, but it's not quite what I wanted. If there is no better way to do it I will use that.

Comment: @Dakkaron see question update (just for clarification)

Comment: I found a way to do that sort of user interaction using raw_input(). Have a look at my answer.