# How to edit a string in terminal, Python

Tags: python, string, input

Just to be clear I've been using vim as a substitute up to now but I want something that doesn't use any external programs.  Python libraries I am definitely down for though.

Want I want is a way for the user to change a string like `"Intel"` to `"Intel Celeron"`. As far as I can tell `Input()` only has options for a prompt, but anything similar that would be great.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context a little bit? For what purpose do you want to change this string; where did you get it, and where do you want to save this change to?

Comment: I'm creating a basic python app to edit entries in a database. The way I have it set up right now is a function that receives a string, sends it to Vim, then returns a string.

Comment: So you want what `input()` does (with a lowercase 'i'!) but displaying an initial, editable value?

Comment: usr2564301 Exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a default editable string for raw\_input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403138/how-to-set-a-default-editable-string-for-raw-input)

Comment: Works perfectly! I think I tried using a similar function before but I didn't call the function properly.