# Readline functionality on windows with python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, readline, python-2.7

I need to import the readline functionality in a program written in python. I am currently using version 2.7 and the 3rd party packages I have seen only work up to version 2.6. Does anyone know of a 3rd party readline package for Windows with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe pyreadline was designed just for this.

`easy_install pyreadline`
or:
`pip install pyreadline`

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline

Also, use the following for forward/reverse compatibility:

```
try:
  import readline
except ImportError:
  import pyreadline as readline
```

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If it causes you any problems please post back in reply.

Comment: +1 @BenBurns: May I ask how the platform compability works?  "If available, import pyreadline (and call it readline).  If not available, import readline directly." Is that correct?  That is, is the preference for the pyreadline version over the plain readline? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but "platform compatibility" was the wrong phrase to use - "forward portability" is more appropriate. This `try`/`except ImportError` pattern allows you to use backported modules on older python releases but still run the code without modification on newer releases.

Comment: Note that pyreadline appears to no longer be maintained and has some significant bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, in 2019, `pyreadline` isn't really developed anymore.

It's far from a "drop-in" replacement, but you could look into [Python Prompt Toolkit.](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit) It provides tab-completion and then some on just about every platform there is. If you're still using Python 2, [you *really should* upgrade](https://pythonclock.org/) but the Prompt Toolkit does appear to support Python 2 with `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.