# Setuptools platform specific dependencies

Tags: python, setuptools

Is there any way to tell setuptools or distribute to require a package on a specific platform?

In my specific case, I'm using `readline`, which comes as part of the standard library on Unix systems, but on Windows I need the `pyreadline` module to replace that functionality (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024952/readline-functionality-on-windows-with-python-2-7)). If I just put it in the requirements It also installs on Unix systems where it's completely useless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I first wrote my answer here, in 2013, we didn't yet have [PEP 496 – *Environment Markers*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/) and [PEP 508 – *Dependency specification for Python Software Packages*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/). Now that we do, the answer is: put environment markers in your `setup_requires`:

```
setup_requires = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'pyreadline; sys_platform == "win32"',
]

setup(
    # ...
    setup_requires=setup_requires,
)
```

This is supported as of [`setuptools` 20.6.8](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v20-6-8), released in May 2016 (support was introduced in [version 20.5](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#id401) but was briefly disabled in intervening releases).

Note that setuptools will use `easy_install` to install those requirements when it is being executed, which is hard to configure for when using `pip` to install the project.

It may better to *not* use setuptools to handle build-time dependencies, and use a `pyproject.toml` file following the recommendations from [PEP 518 – *Specifying Minimum Build System Requirements for Python Projects*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/). Using the PEP 518 build-system with built-time dependencies, means creating a `pyproject.toml` file that looks something like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools",
    "wheel",
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "pyreadline; sys_platform == "win32",
]
```

That's the same list as `setup_requires` but with `setuptools` and `wheel` added. This syntax is supported by `pip` as of [version 10.0.0](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31), released in March 2018.

My old answer, from 2013, follows.

---

`setup.py` is simply a python script. You can create dynamic dependencies in that script:

```
import sys

setup_requires = ['foo', 'bar']

if sys.platform() == 'win32':
    setup_requires.append('pyreadline')

setup(
    # ...
    setup_requires=setup_requires,
)
```

Answer (score 22):

While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16055603/1154610) given by Martijn Pieters was totally valid at the time, Python packaging has changed a lot since then.

The preferred format to distribute packages is using [wheels](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)*. Using wheels it is not possible to run Python code during installation.

Wheel use metadata version two as specified in [PEP 0427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/). [Environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#environment-markers) can be used to specify platform specific dependencies.

Setuptools allows to specify these environment markers as `extras_require` keys. The following example script depends on `pyreadline` for Windows systems and on `pyxdg` for Linux distributions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.0.1',
    extras_require={
        ':sys_platform == "win32"': [
            'pyreadline'
        ],
        ':"linux" in sys_platform': [
            'pyxdg'
        ]
    })
```

*Also release an sdist, so platforms which can't use wheel can still install your package.

Comment: Instead of `':sys_platform == "win32"'`, it's more readable and intuitive to write, `'platform_system=="Windows"'`. And rather than 
`':"linux" in sys_platform'`, you can do `'platform_system=="Linux"'`. This will include both `linux` and `linux2`. Same goes for other platforms, mac is `'platform_system=="Darwin"'`, etc, etc. Reference: [`PEP 508`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers), and [EasyBuilders](https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild/wiki/OS_flavor_name_version)

Comment: As both `install_requires` and `extras_require` have mechanism for platform specific dependencies, just wondering which one is suggested? For example, in `Pipenv`, there is still an issue to support extras_require in Pipfile~

Comment: My understanding is that: ```install_requires``` should be a list of packages that need to live alongside the package, for the lifecycle of the package, for the functionality of the package. This list of packages (```install_requires```) are supplementary to the desired package and provide necessary functionality to the requested package. ```extras_require``` are only installed at the discretion of the user upon requesting additional functionality. ```setup_requires``` are packages necessary for the setup script to continue (required key if you are overloading the install command)

Comment: With PEP 496 and 508, there is no need to use extras anymore. I've updated my answer now that I'm aware how outdated it had become, using the PEP 496 syntax, with a nod to 518 as well.

Answer (score 7):

Other answers are valid and probably more convenient if supporting old `setuptools` versions is required, but there have been some advancements:

Recent versions of setuptools accept [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) style dependency specification:

```
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=[
        'pyreadline; platform_system == "Windows"',
    ],
)
```

Choose the right parameter:

- `install_requires`: what other distributions are needed for the current distribution to work correctly
- `extras_require`: a dictionary mapping the names of optional features to a list of their requirements
- `setup_requires`: other distributions that need to be *present* for the setup script to run correctly
  Note: projects listed in `setup_requires` will NOT be automatically installed. They are simply downloaded to the ./.eggs directory if they’re not locally available already.

There is also an alternative way for supplying these parameters through `setup.cfg` file. [See the documentation for more info](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files).

[PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) introduces a new and more capable way of specifying `setup_requires` in `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[build-system]
# Minimum requirements for the build system to execute.
requires = ['setuptools>"38.3.0"', 'wheel']  # PEP 508 specifications.
```

The feature was implemented in [pip 10.0.0b1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31). Using it one will be able to automatically install and update build system requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    install_requires=(['pymsgbox', 'PyTweening>=1.0.1', 'Pillow', 'pyscreeze']
                    + ["python3-xlib; sys_platform == linux"]
                    + ["python-xlib; sys_platform == linux2"]
                    + ["pyobjc-core; sys_platform == darwin"]
                    + ["pyobjc; sys_platform == darwing"]
                    ),
)
```

This will install speicific versions of libraries depending on whether its `linux2` (for a linux system using `python2`), `linux` (for a linux system using `python3`), `darwin` (for a MacOS system)