# Configure setup.py to install platform-specific libraries

Tags: python

I am writing a small cross-platform library which requires the use of specific libraries when installed on a 'win32' os.  Does anyone know of a simple way to use setup.py to install a given library only if the platform requires it?

I tried creating a conditional in setup.py using sys.platform.endswith('win32'), but perhaps I missed something.

I'd really appreciate a helping hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055403/setuptools-platform-specific-dependencies

Comment: @xmcp - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  While the accepted answer is no longer valid, remco haszing provided an update.

Comment: Please see Remco Hansing's answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32955538/3821347