# how to build a package and include dependencies conditional on os

Tags: python, redis, setuptools

I am trying to build a package that depending on the os of the target machine will include an extra package. More specifically my application depends on `redis` however when the machine where the package is going to be deployed to runs linux, I would like to have `redis-server` as an extra dependency.

What I was thinking to do is to have in my `setup.py` the following lines:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys


install_deps = ['redis']

if sys.platform in ['linux', 'darwin']:
    install_deps.append('redis-server')


setup(
    name="my_app",
    version=version,
    license="BSD",
    author="first_name last_name",
    author_email="first.last@mymail.com",

    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=install_deps,
)
```

That unfortunately doest work since the value of `install_deps` is determined the moment I run 'python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel' on the the machine that keeps the source code and not when I install the wheel on the new (target) machine. I would like when I deploy my package and do `pip install my_app` on a windows pc to install only `redis` as a requirement but when the targer computer runs linux, pip to fetch both `redis` and `redis-server` into the environment.

Is there a way to do that without releasing two different builds, one for windows and another for linux?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42946495/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+conditional+dependencies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16055603/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+platform-specific+dependencies