# Run pythons as .exe files without python installed

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm trying to run a python file on a system without python installed. I'm using py2exe, which gives me a .pyc file which runs fine on my system, but when I give it to a friend without python it tells him Windows can't run the file.

My `setup.py` file contains this;

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['PyVersionControl.py'])
```

When I run py2exe in the commandline, this is output

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\chdick>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe

  3 missing Modules
  ------------------
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
Building 'dist\PyVersionControl.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python34.dll to dist
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd to dist\_tkinter.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy DLL C:\Python34\DLLs\tk86t.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python34\DLLs\tcl86t.dll to dist\

C:\Users\chdick>
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875291/py2exe-missing-modules)?

Comment: Well, the point of `py2exe` is to create `.exe` objects. If you are only giving your friend `.pyc` objects, then yeah, there is no way for them to run it without Python installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `py2exe` to create an executable file from your script (i.e. create `script.exe` from `script.py`).

If you have the correct version of `py2exe` installed, you should be able to type `python -m py2exe.build_exe script.py`.

See the [py2exe package page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/) for details.

Comment: I can make the file using py2exe now, but it gives a .pyc file and not a .exe file, which I can't run without python on my system, which I thought was the whole point of py2exe?

Comment: @CDickson: The output, if completed without error, should be an exe file.  Is there a `dist` folder after you run `py2exe`?  If so, the exe should be found there.

Comment: Ah, I think I found it! Do I need everything in the `dist` folder, or just the library .zip and the exe?

Comment: @CDickson: It depends on how you built the executable.  For more info, review the docs for the [`--bundle-files`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/#the-bundle-files-option-explained) option.

Answer (score -2):

`Py2exe` doesn't support Python 3.4.

The title tells you that, it is only for the second version of Python.

Comment: From the [py2exe homepage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/): "Python 3.3 and later are supported."

Comment: The `2` simply means "to".

Comment: PyPi page says it works for Python 3, the [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/) and [website](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/News) pages are only Python 2.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. I was read the article about py2exe. And there I saw that py2exe don't support python3. And only now I see that this article is old.  SORRY!