# Py2exe missing modules when bundling

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

Before I start, I've checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875291/py2exe-missing-modules) and I already have a `windows=[]` in my setup.py. Note that I named the script I want to convert Tkinter.py.

Here's my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows=['Tkinter.py'],
    options={
        "py2exe":{
            "bundle_files":1,

        }
    }
)
```

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\Tkinter>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe

  3 missing Modules
  ------------------
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
The following modules require a minimum bundle_files option,
otherwise they will not work (currently bundle_files is set to 1):
    tkinter: 2

Please change the bundle_files option and run the build again.
Build failed.
```

I'm trying to bundle it all down to one exe file. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the missing modules issue. They wont cause any problems. For the Bundling issue, just changing the bundle value to 2  worked for me.