# Is it possible to prefill a input() in Python 3's Command Line Interface?

Tags: python, input, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I'm using Python 3.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 (Linux). A piece of my new code looks like this:

`text = input("TEXT=")`

Is it possible to get some predefined string after the prompt, so I can adjust it if needed? It should be like this:

```
python3 file
TEXT=thepredefinedtextishere
```

Now I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> 3 times

```
TEXT=thepredefinedtextish
```

Now I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the variable `text` should be `thepredefinedtextish`

Comment: The short answer is no, but there's bound to be a `curses` or `readline` trick to do this. +1 for the question.

Comment: "Enter blargh (Default: 3)" doesn't do what you ask for, but solves the same problem.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: This doesn't serve exactly the same purpose.  Imagine the user is supposed to enter a list of search paths, with some defaults predefined.  The user will probably want to supplement the predefined list rather than replacing it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Show default value for editing on Python input possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible)

Comment: That's Python. This is Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show default value for editing on Python input possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If your Python interpreter is linked against GNU readline, `input()` will use it.  In this case, the following should work:

```
import readline

def input_with_prefill(prompt, text):
    def hook():
        readline.insert_text(text)
        readline.redisplay()
    readline.set_pre_input_hook(hook)
    result = input(prompt)
    readline.set_pre_input_hook()
    return result
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac OS X by default. Also, I had to change `input()` to `raw_input()` or it would throw "NameError: name '*what I typed*' is not defined".

Comment: @EdwardFalk This has nothing to do with Mac OS X.  You are using Python 2, while this question is about Python 3.

Comment: Ahh, missed that part.

Comment: note this doesn't work on python3.6 inside a Jupiter notebook, or in Pycharm console

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something more smooth but an easy way to do it :

```
inputstring = input("Input your text here ('test' if ignored): ")
if inputstring == '' : inputstring = 'test'
```