# How to write something into input() built-in function from code directly

Tags: python, input, stdin, autofill

I have a need to fill stdin from code directly when input() is waiting for filling.
Is there to do the next:

```
# Here suppose to be some code that will automatically fill input() below
string = input("Input something: ")
# Or here
```

I've heard about subprocess.Popen, but I don't understand how to use it in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to prefill a input() in Python 3's Command Line Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505163/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-input-in-python-3s-command-line-interface)

Comment: @JonSG, no, I need to automate completely this process. No" backspace" and "enter" clicking.

Answer (score 0):

This code is something:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO


class File(StringIO):
    def __init__(self):
        self._origin_out = sys.stdout
        self._origin_in = sys.stdin
        sys.stdout = self
        sys.stdin = self
        self._in_data = ''
        super(File, self).__init__()

    def write(self, data):
        if data == 'My name is:':
            self._in_data = 'Vasja\n'
        else:
            self._origin_out.write(data)

    def readline(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = self._in_data
        if res:
            self._in_data = ''
            return res
        else:
            return sys.stdin.readline(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        sys.stdout = self._origin_out
        sys.stdin = self._origin_in


global_out_file = File()

a = input('My name is:')
print('Entered name is:', a)
```