# Is subprocess the only way to provide input to input()?

Tags: python, input, subprocess

I'm trying to undestand how `input` works.

Given for example a simple function like:

```
def f():
    s = input()
    print(s)
```

There's a way to call `f` and make it print something without building pipelines?

Obviously without typing anything into the termimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to temporarily redefine `sys.stdin`.

eg:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

input_text = 'whatever you want the function to read from input()'

old_stdin = sys.stdin
#Reassign stdin to a StringIO object
sys.stdin = StringIO(input_text)

f()

sys.stdin = old_stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, executing a second python shell in a subprocess is the only way to give input to `input` (Unless you want to redefine `input` in the module).

Instead, you should read from an arbitrary file (and make the default `sys.stdin`). Then, you can simply set a different file - either a temporary one on disk, or a file-like [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object.

```
import sys,StringIO
def f(inputfile=sys.stdin):
    s = inputfile.readline()
    print(s)

# To test, call it like this:
f(StringIO.StringIO('testdata\n'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Can you explain what you mean by reading from an arbitrary file, make the default `sys.stdin` and then setting a different file?

Comment: @RikP. Added demo code. Which part of the sentence is not clear to you?

Comment: Now I understand what you meant, thank you! I was trying to understand how `input` works, but your example was helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I would necessarily recommend this solution, but you could rebind `input` to a different function...

Answer (score -1):

You can't provide a default text to [input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input).

But if you use Linux and Bash, you can do something like this:

```
import readline

def rlinput(prompt, prefill=''):
   readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
   try:
      return raw_input(prompt)
   finally:
      readline.set_startup_hook()

rlinput("Do you want to delete all files?  ", "yes")
```

(modified from this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533142/562769)).

See also:

- readline.[set_startup_hook](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#readline.set_startup_hook)
- readline.[insert_text](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#readline.insert_text)

Comment: Wouldn't this require to press enter?

Comment: Why is it required to use bash here?

Comment: @RikP.: You need to press enter to finish your input. How would you like to submit it else? glglgl: I didn't use other shells. I guess it might work with almost every shell, but it didn't work with the gedits "Better Python Console". As I didn't test it in more shells I just wanted to note that it might not work.