# python console, better than raw_input(), how to offer editable default values?

Tags: python, user-input

`raw_input (prompt_string)` can prompt to input.  How to offer 
**default value**?  And how to make the default value user
**editable**?

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible

Comment: That duplicate and the other answer raises an issue: are you on Windows or a Unix-like platform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest looking into [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) / [pyreadline](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline), or even possibly [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean by user editable. If you want to provide a default they can override:

```
my_input = 'default value'
# user_input will be set to my_input if they just press enter
user_input = raw_input("Enter a string (default: %s):\n" % my_input) or my_input
```

If you want them to be able to set the default value, you either need to use two prompts -- one to set the default, and then another as above -- or else use a tool other than `raw_input`.