# input with input suggestion in Python

Tags: python, windows, input

I do not know how to ask a user for input giving him a hint at the same time.

When I use `raw_input("some description")` a small window pops up and the user must enter something, as the input is completely empty. How to achieve the same, but with something already written to the input box (a hint for the user, which he/she could accept or simply change it)?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533142/1217949

> The standard library functions input() and raw_input() don't have this functionality. If you're using Linux you can use the readline module to define an input function that uses a prefill value and advanced line editing:

```
def rlinput(prompt, prefill=''):
   readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
   try:
      return raw_input(prompt)
   finally:
      readline.set_startup_hook()
```

Comment: sonium - thanks, but unfortunately i am using windows :/ so it looks like there is no solution for the problem, when i want to do this without console (i.e. with a window poping out)?