# Command line input with template / editable command line output

Tags: python, command-line

I want to prompt the user for an input via command line. I can do this with

```
time = raw_input("Enter a time (hh:mm): ")   # Python 2.x
```

or

```
time = input("Enter a time (hh:mm): ")   # Python 3
```

However, I would like to give the user an editable template, i.e. the command line should read:

```
Enter a time (hh:mm): 08:00
```

and the 08:00 should be editable. Now the user can hit enter and '08:00' is returned or he can change it to:

```
Enter a time (hh:mm): 08:45
```

to return '08:45'. Is anything like this possible?

Further info:

- I use Linux with Python 2.7 (but other solutions are fine as well)
- The prompt and the editable text can also be on separate lines.
- I know that this particular example could be solved otherwise ("return for 08:00") but of course this is not so easy for what I actually want to do.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible.

Comment: May be this is what you need.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible

Comment: you can try to implement this with [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) or manipulate `tty` with `termios` module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible does answer my question. Sorry for the duplicate, I did not find that one.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can use print instead of editable input.

> print("Enter a time (hh:mm): ",end="")
>
> time=input()
>
> print(time)