# Is there a way to pre-write something after input?

Tags: python, input, console, console-application

I've been needing this for some time now, and i couldn't find a way to do it. I have a python script that uses python's `input()` function. And if you enter an argument inside of it, it writes something in front of the input, that means `input("hi ")` will output `hi:`  in console, and after a space you can type in. But i don't want that, i want something that if you enter an argument it will pre-write something in the text.
something like this:

```py
input("enter a name: ", "name")

> enter a name: name
                ^^^^
                this is editable by user (can be deleted, modified, etc.)
```

Comment: You will need an advanced library like curses for this.

Comment: Please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible

Comment: There is a way, but it s not simple. You would have to not use `input`, but implement your own function which captures key press events and outputs them to the console. Then you could also control deleting the preselected option.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open for third-party libraries, have a look at [PyInquirer](https://github.com/CITGuru/PyInquirer). A simple example with a default input value that can be modified would look as follows:

```py
from PyInquirer import prompt

question = [
    {
        'type': 'input',
        'name': 'first_name',
        'message': 'Name please',
        'default': 'Max'
    }
]

answer = prompt(question)
print('Hello {}'.format(answer['first_name']))
```