# Is there a way to paste a string into a user input using code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python code, how can you paste a string to a user input?

I would like to edit a text, where you have a line, and the user input already has the line pasted on it by the program, like:

```
line = 'hello there'

input('')
```

Then, when you execute the program, `'hello there'` is in your input and you can edit it into other words

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show default value for editing on Python input possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible)

Comment: Please show some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Like This?

```
default_str = "Hello There"
user_input = default_str + input("{}".format(default_str))
```

Comment: `"{}".format(default_str)` is a long way to write `default_str`

Comment: I want```"Hello There"``` to be editable.

Comment: @DominicRhowelEmbate I see. I'll remove in a minute. Please look at the comment on the original post. It looks like a possible answer!