# Placeholder Input Value

Tags: python, input

I'm very new to **Python** and I'm trying to set a value in the **input()** text. This value comes as an argument **(sys.argv[1])** and I want this value to be able to be **modified**. An example of the input:

```
myvar = int(input("Next input is modifiable: " , sys.argv[1]))
```

So that the output is something like this:

```
Next input is modifiable: 123456
```

Being 123456 something I can change.
I'm not sure if this is able to do but I've been through some sites and didn't find anything similar.

Thanks in advance!

myvar= int(input("Next input is modifiable {}" , sys.argv[1]))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show default value for editing on Python input possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533120/show-default-value-for-editing-on-python-input-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
myvar = int(input("Next input is modifiable: " , sys.argv[1]))
if myvar == "":
    myvar = sys.argv[1]
```